# Does antibiotics weaken immune system or causes Fever

Tags: immune-system, bacteria, antibiotics, fever

If your popping antibiotics everyday, prescribed by your doctor though he asked you to revisit after two months and warned you to ignore any fever symptoms during these two months.
I'm just wondering if Fever (with chill) is expected while taking antibiotics?
I have read somewhere that antibiotics kill good as well as bad bacteria, so does it mean that it weakens my immune system if I keep taking it for two months?
Any advice/precautions while taking antibiotics?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Personalized post are not allowed on this site as no-one is a substitute for your doctor. I will try to edit your post so it is no longer personalized. You can reverse the edits by going into the edit history and pressing rollback. For more info consult the Help center or ask here. Thanks!

Comment: sure, thanks. I'll keep it in mind in future posts.